# Alternatives to linked lists when creating a group of stacked cards in Java?

Tags: java, list, nullpointerexception, linked-list, containers

Let's say that I'm playing a card game that includes a series of stacked cards. I don't know how many stacks of cards I will have before the game starts, but once it does, the number of stacked cards remains the same. My first idea then was to create an array using the number of stacks I was given for an instance of the game, place each of the top cards from those stacks into the array, and then link each card to their stacks using linked lists.

My Card class has the following fields:

```
public class Card {
  private String suit;
  private String value;

  public Card cardInFront = null;
  public Card cardInBack = null;
```

For example, lets say I'm given a deck of standard cards (52 cards, 4 suits, 13 values) to be made into 5 stacks. I distribute the first five cards in round-robin fashion into an array of 5 openings, like so:

```
int numOfPiles = 5;

Card[] cascadePiles = new Card[numOfPiles];
for (int i = 0; i < numOfPiles; i++) {
  cascadePiles[i] = deck.get(i);
}
```

I then continue dealing the cards in round-robin fashion, but connect each card I deal out with both the card in front of it and the card behind it. This is all done with the following code:

```
    int x = 0;
    while (x != numOfPiles) {
      deck.remove(0);
      x++;
    }
    int i = 0;

    while (!deck.isEmpty()) {
      if (i < numOfPiles) {
        Card cardBehind = cascadePiles[i];
        Card temp = cascadePiles[i];
        Card nullSearcher = cascadePiles[i].cardInFront;
        while (nullSearcher != null) {
          cardBehind = temp;
          temp = nullSearcher;
          nullSearcher = temp.cardInFront;
        }
        addToPile(temp, deck.get(0), cardBehind);
        temp.cardIsInPile = PileType.CASCADE;
        deck.remove(0);
        i++;
      } else {
        i = 0;
      }
    }
```

This reason I've done this all in linked lists is because I don't know how many stacks I would need per game. If I used general lists, I would have to know how many to declare before the game started, which I don't. However, by organizing the stacks like this, I've ran into several NullPointerExceptions, and I've read that using null is just bad practice in general. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Why exactly can't you use a `List<Card>[]`? This would neglect the need of the `cardInFront`- and `cardInBack`-references in `Card`.

Comment: you can use general lists even if you don't know how many stacks you would need as `List` supports `add`, `remove` , etc and you don't need to pass size to implementation constructor(e.g. `ArrayList`) upfront

Comment: anyway can you show us the `deck` variable definition along with its class/interface definition ?

Comment: @niceman yeah the deck is defined as :


`List<Card> deck = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < suitArray.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < valueArray.length; j++) {
        deck.add(new Card(suitArray[i], valueArray[j]));
      }
    } `

suitArray and valueArray are just arrays with strings of suits and values found in typical decks

Comment: @Turing85 don't i have to name those instances of List in order to use them?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, something like `ArrayList<LinkedList<Card>>` data type will do the job.

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<Card>> listOfCardStack=new ArrayList<LinkedList<Card>>();

LinkedList<Card> stack0 = new LinkedList<Card>();

Card card0=new Card...

stack0.add(card0);

stack0.add(card1);

...

listOfCardStack.add(stack0);

...
```

Comment: How would I be able to name each stack if I don't know how many stacks I'd get each game?

Comment: you don't have to know the number of stacks you will get. You are using LinkedList class and it implements java.util.List. When you get a new stack, create a linkedList like above, populate it and add to listOfCardStack.